# A question about calculating the data in a shared memory table

Tags: dolphindb

For the data in a shared memory table, if it is calculated simultaneously in two different GUIs, do two different CPU resources are used to do this job at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. If multiple threads are configured, multiple CPU resources will be used.